# Symfony doctrine event PreUpdate always called

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

I don't understand why the event PreUpdate is always called when i show my entity :

abstract class Fiche :

```
/**
 * Fiche
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fiches")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FichesBundle\Repository\FicheRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class Fiche
{    
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateLastUpdate", type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateLastUpdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updateDateLastUpdate()
    {
        $this->setDateLastUpdate(new \Datetime());
    }

    [...]
}
```

class FicheIntervention :

```
/**
 * FicheIntervention
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fiches_intervention")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FichesBundle\Repository\FicheInterventionRepository")
 */
class FicheIntervention extends Fiche
{
    [...]
}
```

the action method :

```
/**
 * @param \FichesBundle\Entity\FicheIntervention $ficheIntervention
 * @return array
 * 
 * @Route("/{id_ficheIntervention}", name="route_fiches_ficheIntervention")
 * @ParamConverter("ficheIntervention", options={"mapping" : {"id_ficheIntervention" : "id"}})
 * @Template()
 */
public function FicheInterventionAction(\FichesBundle\Entity\FicheIntervention $ficheIntervention)
{
    return array(
        "ficheIntervention" => $ficheIntervention
    );
}
```

Everytime i call the action, the date is update. Why ?

Can you help me, plz.

Comment: Seems to me you are creating an instance of the entity class every time you are executing the action. Did you try to fetch the object using the repository instead?

Comment: I  think you need to show more of you code

Comment: same problem when i use $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository(...)->findOneById($id);